# Deletion request: Question 287309

Tags: support, bug, deleted-questions

I figured out the problem with my question, and it was something really obvious - not important enough to keep the question around for.

Unfortunately, the JavaScript that lets me delete a question is broken. Clicking the Delete link does nothing. Can a moderator remove it for me?

https://askubuntu.com/q/287309/95681

Comment: What was the answer anyway?

Comment: Did a close instead. You should at least add the answer here. Am curious.

Comment: The site won't let us delete a recently closed question for a while, that's why the option is missing in the little menu thing.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Yeah... it was really embarassing: I forgot to check the "enable" box next to its port-forwarding entry.. (My router is pretty awesome - it lets you quickly enable/disable port forwards, as well as pick an inbound port that's different from the internal port.)

Comment: Just curious: why was it closed? I know the Reason was "too localized", but, then again, that's what most questions get closed as... regardless of accuracy